# Why am I not allowed to buy a skill after defeating a player in his own castle?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

When playing Fire Emblem Fates, I won some battles against other real players. When you win, you can either choose to recruit one unit from the defeated opponent or to buy a skill from one of his characters.

When I have selected the wanted skill and am about to commit the purchase with the gold I have, it is always impossible for me to "click" and actually commit to buy the skill. It is shown as gray and there are no options to simply click on them for purchase (any of them are available). How can I make this option available so I can have a larger number of skill options for my characters?

Comment: Did you turn the handicap on?

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problems, and I think that it's either that their skill is by default there, so you can't buy them because your character has them, or the skill is locked to the character, as similar shiny locking in Pokemon, maybe.

Comment: What makes you think that this is the reason behind it?

Comment: Aptitude, is a great example, as mentioned from this site:

Comment: What site? I think you submitted your comment without adding it.

Comment: Oh whoops, here's the site: https://www.gamecrate.com/fire-emblem-flu-how-hackers-created-cheating-epidemic/12983 supposedly, since aptitude isn't easily hacked into other players, it's still possible, but Nintendo makes it so some hacked skills can't be transferred, unless you recruit the character, which if they also come from a different player, is also unrecruitable.

Comment: There's the site.

Comment: When I mean shiny locking, I mean you can't trade it to another person. It's stuck on your game file, and it's untradable, such as a shiny Zygarde, perfect forme. My friend had a shiny mega salamence he hacked in, and was able to trade it, but shiny 100% Zygarde? Out of the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I've read the linked article. However, in the article, it even states that skills were not made unavailable due to hackers: `Nintendo couldn’t simply make that skill off limits in My Castle` The hacking ruined the metagame and made it unenjoyable to use My Castle as everyone had Aptitude on all of their characters. Your answer states that hacked skills were prevented from spreading, but your article says that it wasn't and that *that* was the problem. Also, that's a preventative measure for GTS to keep hacked Pokémon out of official tournaments. You can still trade them to friends.